# How can I enforce a named constructor for various types?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to be able to enforce that any type should have a named constructor `fromMap`.

```
class User extends X {
    User.fromMap(Map data) { ... };
}

class Entry extends X {
    Entry.fromMap(Map data) { ... };
}
```

In this example, I'd like to know that any subclass of `X` has a `fromMap` constructor.

Comment: Yup! That's a shame

Comment: Named constructors are not methods that can be inherited from parent classes, in any language, constructors are special methods that belongs only to the class you are calling on.